# Date Format in a text box, it is not appearing upon clicking

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Upon clicking on the text box, which is supposed to be showing a date picker for me to choose the date, but it is not showing at all, I wanted it to be shown upon clicking on it.

```html
  <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: It is saying $ is not defined. That means it is missing jquery script. Also check if you have datetimepicker script.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you haven't used script links for JQuery and/or datetimepicker.

You can try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, may I know which script line is necessary to be in, for the datepicker to work, I have a few other bootstraps that I am using for the website, and it messes up everything when i copied and paste the whole bootstrap.

Comment: Check whether you have these script lines: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" /> (For DateTimePicker Styles),     
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script> (For DateTimepPicker to work like click events, on blur, on change events etc.)

Comment: If you have above links, check for JQuery script: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I had the following lines inserted, but the date picker is still unable to work.

Comment: @addny_1, I could see that you haven't linked your stylesheet links and javascript links in code pen that's why it is not getting it. To link your stylesheet click on Settings above the codepen > click CSS tab > scroll down and copy first link: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css, then similarly add the second one. Don't put <link rel="stylesheet"... > inside it just the links. You just did for CSS. Now you have to do it for JS as well. So copy js links that I provided in answer and paste it in JS tab one by one without <script> tag. Just paste the links.

Comment: You can directly use my answer to fulfill your requirement as well. This is easiest way.

Comment: Hi, sir. my apologies, I am new at the codepen website, please bear with me. I've just set the links in separate css/js accordingly but it is still not working.

Comment: @addny_1 no problem. Happy to help :) I could see that your CSS is properly referenced, but your script is not. Their order is not proper. Its order should be 1) moment.min.js 2) jquery.min.js 3) bootstrap.min.js and finally 4) datetimepicker.min.js. Just go to JS Tab and drag their position according to the order I mentioned just now.

Comment: Order is very important when you refer scripts.

Comment: hi, I've set the order as mentioned, somehow it is not still showing, am I missing something :\

Comment: @addny_1, You have written your jquery script twice ie in HTML tab and JS TAB in code pen. remove the <script> and everything inside it from HTML tab. Just keep html part. And from JS tab just keep the scripts, remove the <script> tag. You have to make these changes in code pen not in settings.

Answer (score 0):

As we discussed remove the script tag completely from HTML window, and remove  tag except the actual JS from JS window.

Your Code pen's code should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I've managed to get it working, appreciate the effort for solving this, but another problem occurred my navigation bar is messed up now after inserting the lines, perhaps it is due to my other bootstraps. :/

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></scri

Comment: </script> These are the 3 lines that are in the script too

Comment: Remove these scripts that and use the scripts that I shared with you.

Comment: my navigation bar and layout for the website are all in a mess upon executing that action.

Comment: Actually you didn't mentioned the navigation bar in your question. Apologize for any confusion. Can you send me the screenshot?